# IIS 6.0: AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed influencing maximum upload size in Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, iis-6, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

The IIS MetaBase.xml file entiry "AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed" can make any difference in uploading sharepoint 2007 files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed` (and other ASP-specific settings like `AspBufferingLimit`) setting is an **ASP (classic) limit**. It doesn't affect ASP.NET or other web frameworks running on IIS.

[Here is a short tutorial](http://www.msexperts.org/blogs/mark/archive/2008/10/23/increasing-the-maximum-upload-limit-on-a-sharepoint-site.aspx) describing the steps that are necessary for increasing the upload limits of a Sharepoint 2007 site:

1. Increase the Web Applications Upload limit.
2. Increase the HTTP Timeout.
3. Increase the Execution Timeout and MaxRequestLength in web.config